# How to create a simple administration panel for my joomla plugin

Tags: joomla

I think the problem lies in my xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<extension version="2.5" type="plugin" group="content">
   <install>
    <name>Content - eya</name>
    <author>eya</author>
    <creationDate>February 2013</creationDate>
    <copyright>(C) 2013 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.</copyright>
    <license>GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt</license>
    <authorEmail>anigag@grzeit.com</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>www.eya.com</authorUrl>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
    <description>Adds eya plugin ot your site</description>
    <files>
     <filename plugin="eya">eya.php</filename>
   </files>
   </install>

   <administration >
       <filename>admin.php</filename>
   </administration>
</extension>
```

This is my main php file that executes the content:eya.php.

I have got another file (admin.php) that takes 2 session variables from eya.php and put them in an iframe. There are two problems. One is that I dont know if the eya.php runs everytime before admin.php (or at least once to set the session variables). The second problem is that I dont know how to display only the admin.php and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

to build an admin interface for your plugin just add the config part to your xml

```
<config>
   <fields name="params">
       <fieldset name="basic">
           <field name="testfield"    type="text" default="mytest" label="field_label" description="field_description" />
       </fieldset>
   </fields>
</config>
```

but I didn't get the part of your admin.php/eya.php

Comment: But i need to put the contents of the admin.php inisde. how do i do that?

Comment: `$params->get(param_name)` is what is used to get data from the parameters.
Also, remove your `<install>` tags from your XML file

Comment: but i have no parameters in my plugin. what removing the install tags has got anything to do iwth it

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  you ask for an adminpanel, but you do not have any parameter?